# Ambiguous equality of collections when verifying arguments with mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Does mockito verify method match the same instances of a collection or does it verify the elements of a collection?
If I put a breakpoint to Page#equals() method, it doesn't event get hit. Only Page#hashCode() does. Any idea why Mockito doesn't consider 2 implementations of Set equal when they have the same elements ?

```
Set<Page> pagesToRemove = Sets.newHashSet();
// add a few pages
Set<Page> copy = ImmutableSet.copyOf(pagesToRemove)
pageManager.removePages(copy);
verify(pageManager, new Times(1)).removePages(pagesToRemove);
```

Equals and HashCodes methods on Page have default implementations inherited from Object.

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted: pageManager.removePages(
>       (HashSet) [{ pageId : null; parentId : null; firstChild : null; nextSibling : null }, etc...] );
>   -> at com.fg.edee.integration.service.PageServiceTest.testRemove(PageServiceTest.java:60)
>   Actual invocation has different arguments: pageManager.removePages(
>       (RegularImmutableSet) [{ pageId : null; parentId : null; firstChild : null; nextSibling : null }, etc..] );

Comment: I believe Mockito is simply using equals to check for equality.  Can you try to do something like `assertEquals(pagesToRemove, copy)` to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ArgumentMatcher when verifying method invoking with reference typed objects as arguments. See [here](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few tests and figure out that it's just a HashSet hashCode thing. As I said, I was using native Object#hashCode and :

> A key limitation is that in the standard Java implementation, hash
>   codes do not uniquely identify an object. They simply narrow down the
>   choice of matching items, but it is expected that in normal use, there
>   is a good chance that several objects will share the same hash code.

Which is quite misleading because native Object#hachCode() method returns always the same integer within the execution.

Comment: Key problem here could be that you have implemented (overridden) the ``equals`` method for the ``Page`` object, but not the ``hashCode`` method. That's not good because all collection implementations relying on the hashcode break. If two `Page` objects are considered equal by your ``equals`` method, they *must* share the same hash code. See Item 9 ("If you override ``equals``, *always* override ``hashCode``) in Bloch's "Effective Java" which I strongly recommend to read.

Comment: but HashSet#contains method computes hashCode on the input parameter and tries if there is an element in a set, being tested for equality, that has this hashCode. And considering the fact, that X Object#hashCode calls on the same Object instance don't always return the same hashCode, then Sets with X identical instances cannot most likely equal. The equal method is quite irrelevant in this usecase

Comment: I got in to this situation because those Entities were destroyed and there were no business keys to use for computing hashCode, so I called Object#hashCode... I resolved this by keeping the original 'beforeDestroyHashcode' before I destroy the entity

Comment: True, the ``hashSet``/``equals`` implementations don't play a role here because google's ``ImmutableSet.copyOf`` puts references to the original objects in a new set, the objects in the set are not copied. *But* you said:  *X Object#hashCode calls on the same Object instance don't always return the same hashCode*, that is definately wrong, or, at least, would break the [general contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for the ``hashCode`` method!